# Gradle dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Error in gradle file in android studio.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mih.demo2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Error in  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Guide me to solve this Error In the android studio. I search a lot but cannot find the solution. 
[image]

Comment: Please provide the exactly error message! Btw, did you try increase target/compile SDK version to 28?

Comment: i did it but not solved

Comment: Share the screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Please add the entire error that you get and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these flags in your gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

then use SDK version 28 for both compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mih.demo2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

It works fine!

Comment: You should increase target and compile SDK version to 28. Then add those flags to gradle.properties and then sync your gradle. I test it again and it works for your gradle. If not, put more comments with code please. @MIH

Comment: sir, I did it but it shows a message "unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 because no repositories are defined."

Comment: check this, its a sample project with your gradle. it works fine http://s2.picofile.com/file/8373101150/test.rar.html
@MIH

Comment: from this link it cannot be download will you send me google drive link please Sir

Comment: use this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h1mVzjO-xN6X6pgNnw_g9qvfe1B_SpEM @MIH

Comment: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:3-19:17 to override.

Comment: I also add screenshot

Comment: Of course when I remove these two lines 

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

from gradle.properties, I have same error.
adding these two lines to gradle.properties file, will solve the problem.
check it again please. @MIH